# Need help to stretch div element

Tags: html, css

I've made a sketch of a website which header and footer stretches to infinity but the navigation box and content box (middle part) is stuck up on the same size. Hence if I start stretching my browser it starts looking bad.

Question: how can I make it so that the middle part is stretching accordingly?

```
<div id="main">
<div id="header">
    <h1><b>Website Header</b></h1>
    </div>
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<div id="submain">
    <div id="chat">
        <h3>CHAT BOX</h3>
        </div>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Content goes here</h1>
        </div>
    <div id="subright">
        <div id="members">
            <h4>Member Area</h4>
            </div>
        <div id="recent">
            <h4>Recent Activity</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="footer">
    <b>Some footer, 2013</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

my **css** file:

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 15px;
    background: #66FF66;
}
img {
    border: none;
}
a {
    color: #8D0D19;
}
a:hover {
    color: #1A446C;
}
#header {
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    background: #1A446C;
    color: #D4E6F4;
}
#header h1 {
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0;
}
#nav {
    text-align:center;
    /*word-spacing:240px;*/
    float: center;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1px 0em;
    color: #D4E6F4;
    background: none;
}
#nav a {
    color: #D4E6F4;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav li a:hover {
    background: #383;
}
#nav ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 98px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
#submain {
    height: 600px;
    width:1080px;
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 0px 0em;
    background: #3366FF;
}
#chat {
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 2em;
    color: #D4E6F4;
    background: #8D0D19;
}
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 1em;
    color: #D4E6F4;
    background: #330033;
}
#subright {
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0em;
    background: #3366FF;
}
#members {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 2em;
    color: #D4E6F4;
    background: #8D0D19;
}
#recent {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    height: 80%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 2em;
    color: #D4E6F4;
    background: #336600;
}
#footer {
    clear: both;
    height: 2em;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    background: #1A446C;
    color: #D4E6F4;
}
```

Comment: Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J9GUq/

Comment: Please select the answer that you feel is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for everything not streching is becuase you didn't apply any styles to the up most parent container, in your case `<div id="main"></div>`.

You need to add, 100% width to the `#main` div, float it left and set overflow hidden so the height stretches to fit the content inside.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 15px;
    background: #66FF66;
}
img {
    border: none;
}
a {
    color: #8D0D19;
}
a:hover {
    color: #1A446C;
}
#main {
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    background:red;
}
#header {
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    background: #1A446C;
    color: #D4E6F4;
}
#header h1 {
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0;
}
#nav {
    text-align:center;
    /*word-spacing:240px;*/
    float: center;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1px 0em;
    color: #D4E6F4;
    background: none;
}
#nav a {
    color: #D4E6F4;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav li a:hover {
    background: #383;
}
#nav ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hchdb/2/)**

Comment: I think I should change #submain in this particular case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you specify `min-width` or `width` (as you've done for #nav and #submain respectively), that's going to constrain the width of the element(s) on which they are applied. Remove them so that they are not constrained. Of course, you'd have to layout other elements within those boxes so that they flow smoothly.